# Finding mismatches in tuples and merging them in Python

Tags: python, compare, tuples

I have two tuples `a = ((1, 'AB'), (2, 'BC'), (3, 'CD'))` and `b = ((1, 'AB'), (2, 'XY'), (3, 'ZA'))`. By analysing these two tuples, it can be found that there are mismatches in the tuples, i.e, `(2, 'BC')` is present in `a` but  `(2, 'XY')` is present in `b`.

I need to figure out such mismatches and come with a tuple that has the values as

```
result = ((2, 'BC', 'XY'), (3, 'CD', 'ZA'))
```

(order shall be preserved)

The closest reference I could catch hold is [Comparing sublists and merging them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574362/comparing-sublists-and-merging-them), but this is for lists and I couldn't find a way to work with tuples.

Is there a way by which I can perform this operation?

Comment: Where's your code so far? Where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Can ignore this case. Only if there is a mismatch, the result should have the item in the tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there cannot be missing "keys" from `a` or `b` (or those values should be ignored), I would turn `b` into a dictionary, then loop on `a` and compare values.

```
a = ((1, 'AB'), (2, 'BC'), (3, 'CD'))
b = ((1, 'AB'), (2, 'XY'), (3, 'ZA'))

b = dict(b)

mismatches = [(k,v,b[k]) for k,v in a if b.get(k,v) != v]

print(mismatches)
```

result:

```
[(2, 'BC', 'XY'), (3, 'CD', 'ZA')]
```

the solution has the advantage of being almost 1 line, fast (because of dict lookup) and preserves order.

the `if b.get(k,v) != v` condition safeguards against `a` having one tuple with a number not in `b` dictionary. In that case, default value of `get` returns `v` and the condition is `False`

Comment: Seems like it works, even if we do `b.get(k)` instead of `b.get(k, v)` in `mismatches` line

Comment: not passing default value as value from `a` means that you'll get a key error when `a` has an extra key. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are guaranteed to have the same order of the numbers in the tuples, you can do something like:

```
[ai + (bi[1],) for ai, bi in zip(a, b) if ai != bi]
```

and if there is no guarantee on the order you can do:

```
[ai + (bi[1],) for ai, bi in zip(sorted(a), sorted(b)) if ai != bi]
```