# Python - Comparing list of lists

Tags: python

[image]

I have a list with 3 lists and 3 other lists with 3 lists inside.

I want to compare the first index of list A with the first indexes of the first list B ...

Comparing the 22 with the 2,6,3 ... the 3 with the 4,4,66

Can help me ?

```
a = [[22,3,3], [5,3,7],[1,6,3]]

b = [[2,4,7], [6,4,8],[3,66,13]] , [[2,23,6], [5,13,7],[11,6,34]] , [[22,53,6], [54,3,7],[11,6,33]]
```

Comment: Where's `4,4,66`, and what would you do after comparing, any attempts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, comparison sublists and making a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674108/python-comparison-sublists-and-making-a-list)

Comment: I put a image to explain better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
a = [[22,3,3], [5,3,7],[1,6,3]]

b = [[2,4,7], [6,4,8],[3,66,13]] , [[2,23,6], [5,13,7],[11,6,34]] , [[22,53,6], [54,3,7],[11,6,33]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        for x in range(len(b)):
            for y in range(len(b[x])):
                for z in range(len(b[y])):
                    if (a[i][j]==b[x][y][z]):
                        print('true')
                    else:
                        print('false')
```

As it prints true or false it is going to give you a long output. You can modify it as per your needs, and it compares properly as you mentioned in your question.